# Erro ao utilizar o método firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() em um array

Tags: firebase, timestamp, firestore

Estou criando um sistema de dúvidas e respostas, e nesse sistema e nesse sistema preciso que as respostas entrem em um array com o nome de quem responde, o valor de sua resposta e o timestamp do horário em que a resposta foi encaminhada. Segue o código:

```
        enviar_resposta: function(id_duvida, index){
            let path = firebase.firestore().collection('database').doc(this.id_cliente).collection('assembleia').doc(this.id_assembleia).collection('duvidas').doc(this.id_duvida)
            let resposta = {                
                respostas : [
                    {   nome: this.nome, 
                        resposta:this.nova_pergunta,
                        data_duvida: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                        }
                ]           
            }
            path.update({
                resposta : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(resposta.respostas[0])
            })
        },
```

O meu problema está no timestamp, de alguma maneira ele não está me permitindo inserir os dados do timestamp dentro do array, segue o erro em questão:

[image: Erro Firestore]

Pelo que entendi o erro está relacionado a algum tipo de problema com o timestamp e o fato dele ser permitido usar apenas metodos .set() e .update(). Alguém sabe como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma resposta. O servertimestamp() é uma maneira depreciada para utilização com arrayunion(), por isso o google apenas não está mais utilizando.
Para criar timestamps através do firestore é necessário usar apenas o new Date(). o código funcionando ficará dessa maneira:

```
        enviar_resposta: function(id_duvida, index){
            let path = firebase.firestore().collection('database').doc(this.id_cliente).collection('assembleia').doc(this.id_assembleia).collection('duvidas').doc(this.id_duvida)
            let resposta = {                
                respostas : [
                    {   nome: this.nome, 
                        resposta:this.nova_pergunta,
                        data_duvida: new Date()
                        }
                ]           
            }
            path.update({
                resposta : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(resposta.respostas[0])
            })
        },
```

Para mais informações sobre o problema acessar: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/449